# Warning in vscode with git: is on a file system that does not record ownership

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm using vscode with GitLens and when I open a git repository and try to make pull, but the command doesn't work and always receive the warning "is on a file system that does not record ownership".

I can work perfectly with the repository in Sublime merge.

Also, I've added the option git config --global --add safe.directory '*' but it seem doesn't work in vscode.

I would like to know how to work with the repo in this volume and if it is possible remove the warning.

Comment: What's the question? If you don't want the warning - move the repo to a volume that has a file system which supports recording owners.

Comment: Yes, I would like to work with the repo in the current volume. I can't move it. Its not only the warning, the pull command doesn't work.

Comment: Then post that. To get rid of that warning you have to move it to a different volume.

Answer (score -1):

```
git config --global --add safe.directory "*"
```

<del>I met the same case and this simply works.</del>

Not working for the op but anyone seeing this can have a try

Comment: A year ago the OP said it didn't work.

Comment: Well I didn't see that